# Configure Office workgroup templates for Office365 from SharePoint location

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, sharepoint, templates, workgroup

### Problem statement

We have updated custom corporate templates to be used by staff for Microsoft Word, PowerPoint and Excel and these were loaded on Microsoft SharePoint.

We would like to ensure that our staff always use the latest available templates and make it easy for them to select the required template directly from the Microsoft Office applications. Similar to how you can create a document from a custom template in e.g. MS Word for a flyer, calendar or report.

### Possible solution

Years ago in a previous job I saved the templates on each users laptop in a specified folder for it to appear in the Office client, similar to this: [Custom templates displayed in Office applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuSYB.png)

For this implementation, we want to make use of the Office templates saved in SharePoint.

I have looked at these resources, but they both explain a physical folder location *(I would like to use SharePoint)* :

- [Using Workgroup Templates across Your Network](https://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/using-workgroup-templates-across-network/)
- [Workgroup Templates](https://bettersolutions.com/word/templates/workgroup.htm)

### Requirements

There are a few requirements that I have to simplify the implementation and management of these templates:

1. Simple rollout to our users, preferable from a central location such as M365/O365 portal
2. Templates to be referenced from SharePoint and not a network location as in the links above

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not the only one who wants this, and apparently it's possible - see [Matti Paukkonen's blog entry about it](https://mattipaukkonen.com/2019/12/03/sharing-office-document-templates-from-sharepoint/). (_found via [Google for "Office 365 Open Templates From Sharepoint](https://www.google.com/search?q=office+365+open+template+from+sharepoint)_)

Comment: Here is an article from Microsoft, "[Create an organization assets library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library)". The templates are for all users in your organization, after you specify a library as an organization assets library, users log their account into Microsoft 365 apps, they would find templates via clicking New.

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog entry but haven't try it yet. Seems pretty complete https://www.mobile-mentor.com/insights/centrally-deploy-and-manage-office-templates-using-microsoft-intune-tutorial-how-to

The high-level summary given in that article says:

> At a high level, these are the steps involved
>
> 1. Upload the templates to a SharePoint site and configure access
> 2. Create and assign the script to sync the SharePoint site on the end
>    user’s device
> 3. Create and assign the configuration policy which points the office
>    applications to the synced SharePoint site

Comment: A bare link is not a sufficient answer. Please at least summarize and provide steps quoting from the original as needed.

Comment: Although the article describes a method using Intune, it seems like you could adapt this by: 1) deploying the script in another way - through regular logon scripts or Group Policy perhaps 2) configure office to point to the offline copy of the sharepoint site using Group Policy